# Debugging ping pong game in Python

Tags: python, pygame, pong

I'm tired, and I've tried to run this all day. IT's a game of pong where the ball bounces off the wall and comes into contact with the user's "Slab" or paddle. I've treid to debug for a while, and turns out my iCollide and the iGet_Velocity parts have been causing a lot of issues.

```
from livewires import games, color
games.init (screen_width = 640, screen_height = 480, fps = 50)

class Ball (games.Sprite):
    def update (self):
        if self.right>544:
            self.dx = -self.dx
        if self.top > 11 or self.bottom > 470:
            self.dy = -self.dy
        if self.left < 0:
            self.iLost()

    def iLost (self):
        games.Message (screen = self.screen,
                       x = 340,
                       y = 240,
                       text = "Game Over",
                       size = 90,
                       color = color.red,
                       lifetime = 250,
                       after_death = self.screen.quit)                       

    def ihandle_collision (self):
        new_dx, new_dy = Slab.iVelocity()
        self.dx += self.dx + new_dx  #For handling collision, must take velocity of the mouse object and put add it to the velocity of the ball.
        self.dy += self.dy + new_dy

class Slab (games.Sprite):
    def update (self):
        self.x = games.mouse.x
        self.y = games.mouse.y
        self.iCollide()

    def iCollide (self):
        for Ball in self.overlapping_sprites:
            Ball.ihandle_collision()

    def iVelocity (self):
        self.get_velocity()


def main():
    #Backgrounds
    pingpongbackground = games.load_image ("pingpongbackground.jpg", transparent = False)
    games.screen.background = pingpongbackground
    #Ball: Initializing object and setting speed.
    ballimage = games.load_image ("pingpongball.jpg", transparent = True)
    theball = Ball (image = ballimage,
                    x = 320,
                    y = 240,
                    dx = 2,
                    dy = 2)
    games.screen.add(theball)
    #Paddle: Initializing ping pong object and setting initial poisition to the initial mouse position
    slabimage = games.load_image ("pingpongpaddle.jpg", transparent = True)
    theslab = Slab (image = slabimage,
                    x = games.mouse.x,
                    y = games.mouse.y)
    games.screen.add(theslab)
    games.mouse.is_visible = False
    games.screen.event_grab = True
    games.screen.mainloop()

main ()
```

Comment: can you provide some details on the specific issues you're seeing? otherwise it's less of a question and more of a code review

Comment: Sorry. Upon contact with the paddle, the game freezes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, without having some more data, I can't say for certain what is wrong.  But it looks like your collision response code is a bit screwy.  For example, in the first section you should do this to handle your boundary conditions properly:

```
def update (self):
    if self.right>544 and self.dx > 0:
        self.dx = -self.dx
    if (self.top > 11 and self.dy < 0) or (self.bottom > 470 and self.dy > 0):
        self.dy = -self.dy
    if self.left < 0:
        self.iLost()
```

Also your collision response code is a bit wonky.  This is untested, but it does approximately the right thing:  (EDIT: Rewrote this with more comments so that it would be more clear)

```
def iCollide (self):
    for Ball in self.overlapping_sprites:

        #Extract the components of the slab's velocity
        slab_vx, slab_vy = self.iVelocity()

        #Compute relative components of slab velocity
        rel_vx, rel_vy = Ball.dx - slab_vx, Ball.dy - slab_vy

        #Determine the time of intersection and the normal direction
        #This is done to compute which face the ball hits
        #Initially suppose that the objects intersect at t=infinity
        t, nx, ny = 100000, 0, 0

        #Check left/right faces
        if rel_vx != 0:
            #Check if ball hits left face
            toi = (self.left - Ball.right) / rel_vx
            if toi < t:
                t, nx, ny = toi, -1, 0

            #Check if ball hits right face
            toi = (self.right - Ball.left) / rel_vx

            if toi < t:
                t, nx, ny = toi, 1, 0

        #Check top/bottom faces:
        if rel_vy != 0:

            #Check if ball hits top face
            toi = (self.top - Ball.bottom) / rel_vx
            if toi < t:
                t, nx, ny = toi, 0, -1

            #Check if ball hits right face
            toi = (self.bottom - Ball.top) / rel_vx
            if toi < t:
                t, nx, ny = toi, 0, 1

        #Check if impact force properly corrects velocity
        if Ball.dx * nx + Ball.dy * ny < 0:

            #Reflect the ball's position
            Ball.dx += Ball.dx * nx * 2.0
            Ball.dy += Ball.dy * ny * 2.0

        #Check if cursor movement is not pushing ball into paddle:
        if slab_vx * nx + slab_vy * ny < 0:
            Ball.dx += slab_vx
            Ball.dy += slab.vy
```

What you should try to do is find which face of the slab the ball intersects, then reflect the balls velocity according to that direction.  Now this code is by no means tested, since I couldn't get your example to run.  However it should give you an idea of what the correct solution ought to do.

Comment: Hey, would you mind explaining the compute time part? And shouldn't it be slab.iVelocity as we'd want the ball to have the speed that the slab hits it with?

Comment: Great, great answer. I find it fascinating that you were able to type that function as quickly as you did earlier. It doesn't execute to perfection yet, there are a few other bugs in other functions, but I understand the logic behind it now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

These two lines look sketchy:

```
    self.dx += self.dx + new_dx
    self.dy += self.dy + new_dy
```

Try:

```
    self.dx += new_dx
    self.dy += new_dy
```

Comment: I fixed that earlier, forgot to save it when I did though. I'm more concerned with whether the objects are logically communicating with one another...

Comment: That still won't work though.  The ball would pass right though a stationary cursor.